# What am I doing wrong with this 3x3 Mean filter?

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap

I am trying to implement a Mean Filter on a coloured image for an Android application. When I apply the filter on a chosen image.

The original image:

[image]
The filtered image
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while calculating Mean / Average values from array of pixels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074678/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-while-calculating-mean-average-values-from-arra)

Answer (score 2):

At each pixel you read the color value from `pixels[index]`, but the index variable is an index to the filtered array, not the original image. You should be reading the pixel data at index `x+filterX+width*(y+filterY)`, and be careful at the edges of the image.

A bigger problem is that the sums of red, green, and blue never get reset to 0, which means they'll keep accumulating pixel values. This should explain the discoloring. Add:

```
        sumR = 0;
        sumG = 0;
        sumB = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < RArray.length; i++) {
            sumR += RArray[i];
            sumG += GArray[i];
            sumB += BArray[i];
        }
```

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the color space?

Comment: I thought the discoloring could be caused by a color space problem but it's probably another thing (not resetting the sums for red, green and blue to zero)

Comment: the program crashes for some reason when I change the pixels[index] part and also the resetting the sumR/G/B.

Comment: If the program crashes it must have some error.

Comment: I'm sorry but "crashes for some reason" isn't really enough information. What do you do at the edges of the image where the filter window includes pixels outside the image? If you don't handle that case you'll get "array index out of bounds" errors.

Comment: Which loop are you referring to? It doesn't look like you've updated the code in the answer.